# php not losing session data after session_destroy

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to use sessions in php and not getting very far. All of my php pages are called via ajax from a single 'portal page.' I store information between ajax calls using sessions. I have an include file which is the first file in every ajax page which has session_start as the very first method call. Session data seems to be saved ok. However I'm having a problem getting rid of the session when I'm finished with it on the user logout page.
The logout page is an ajax page which basically does this:

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
         setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,$params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
    }
//code to unset session variables
        session_destroy();
```

if i try and write a session variable to screen on the logout page it is empty as you would expect. However if i refresh the portal page and display the session_id to screen it is the same id as the one from the last session that was just supposedly destroyed. If i close the browser and open it again I have a new session

the php session cookie is still in the browser cookies after the logout page has been called. Naturally a page refresh will load this cookie. Why isn't the cookie being deleted? Is my code faulty or is it something to do with the fact it is an ajax page?

Comment: why do you set a cookie there? and why do you call `$_SESSION = array();`?

Comment: Could it be that you still have saved the session id in either the url or a hidden form field?

Comment: are you sure you are not a programmer ?

Comment: and what's the problem? If you destroy session on the server and delete whole SESSION array, than no more data are associated with that session name

Comment: try to check browser cookies, if you find it. Maybe your browser doesn't remove cookie.

Comment: @Krab - you are right there is no problem in that there is nothing associated with that session id. However I'm learning php so I'm curious why it doesnt work as expected. I've tried this in 3 browsers and yes the cookie is still there. The problem is that it isn't being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a cookie, the cookie deletion will happen in the request that tells the browser to delete the cookie. But during that request the cookie will still exist. So to see the cookie still existing in the call that deletes the cookie is expected behavior.

So during/after logout, the cookie will still exist. The cookie will only be gone 1 request AFTER the request that clears the cookie.

If the cookie still exists in multiple requests after the logout, then try increasing the TIME difference for the cookie from 42000 to (11 hours) to 90000 (25 hours). Maybe you have a timezone difference between you and the client

Comment: Hi. I keep refreshing the page and the cookie is still there. Aren't these refreshes separate requests then? Does a refresh count as the same request that deleted the cookie because I am using ajax? I reload the page by entering the url in a sepatate tab and teh cookie is still there. I make other requests to the domain and the cookie is still there :)

Comment: how do you know the cookie is still there? Are you looking with javascript? with php? with firebug ?

Comment: hi. looking in the browser's cookie collection and also writing out the session_id to screen which is showing the same value both before and after i have logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's an instance of the function **session_start()** on any page, the browser will typically create and maintain session cookie ,cookie name on the client machine. The session ID will remain the same until the browser or web page is closed, or `session_regenerate_id()` is called on the server.

I'm guessing there's probably an instance of `session_start()` on the logout page which is why you keep seeing a session cookie in your browser cookie section. However, this shouldn't worry you, since you've deleted any associated data stored on that "session cookie id" with `session_destroy()` on the server side the session cookie name you're seeing in your browser cookie section is just a dummy session ID waiting around for when you'll start storing session data again on the server.

If you don't want to see the session cookie ID which typically starts with PHPSESSID~ then you should make sure there's no call to `session_start()` on your logout page, but I must say that's pointless.

Hope that helps.